# How to submit the content of contact form 7 to external CRM

Tags: wordpress, crm

I would like to submit the content of contact form 7 to external CRM after the email of contact form 7 was sent.

How can I retrieve the data of the form?

Which hook I should use?

How to submit the form to external url?

Thank you,

Sam

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access submitted data by adding following action.
For OOP's

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail',array($this,'create_new_user_registration'),10,1);
```

for simple function call -

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail','create_new_user_registration',10,1);
```

After add this action you need to create a function.In that function you can access submitted data-

```
 public function create_new_user_registration($contact_form)
    {
        $wpcf7 = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();
        $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
        //Below statement will return all data submitted by form.
        $data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        //suppose you have a field which name is 'email' then you can access it by using following statement.
        $user_passed_email =  $data['email'];



    }
```

similar to above example you can access any field of form submitted by contact form 7.

Answer (score 12):

To access the submitted form after the mail has been sent, you can do the following:

```
// hook your function to wpcf7_mail_sent
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'handle_form_submission' ); 

function handle_form_submission( $contact_form ) {
    $title = $contact_form->title;
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if ( $submission ) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
        // handle the data here e.g. submit to CRM
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end I found a solution with the wordpress plugin: 
Contact-Form-7: 3rd-Party Integration.

It didn't work at the beginning I had to add another plugin: "Forms: 3rd-Party Migration" which is an upgrade to the " Contact-Form-7: 3rd-Party Integration".

You can read about it at:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/forms-3rdparty-migrate/

You can stay only with: "Forms: 3rd-Party Migration".

Comment: Please provide more information than just a bunch of product names and URLs to those products.

Answer (score 0):

The *wpcf7_before_send_mail* hook also has one more advantage than *wpcf7_mail_sent*. You can abort the process of sending the form and display a custom message to the user.

Parameters passed to the hook:

```
do_action_ref_array( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', array(
    $this->contact_form,
    &$abort,
    $this,
));
```

Source: https://github.com/rocklobster-in/contact-form-7/blob/master/includes/submission.php#L767

To customize the message you can use this hook:

```
apply_filters( 'wpcf7_display_message', $message, $status )
```

It's helpful when integrating with API.